# Dynamically creating Primefaces line chart produces JS 'Unexpected Identifier' error and no chart

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, charts

I'm writing a test application which lets the user create both a bar chart and line chart from the same dynamically generated data. The bar chart is successfully created, but the line chart results in a blank page. So far, it looks like a javascript / jqplot problem. I examined the following possible causes:

**1) The accuracy of the Java methods**

The bean method for creating the line chart:

```
public LineChartModel lineModelMethod() {
    ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries();
    series1Name = "Series 1";
    series1List = facade.chartQuery(idmid, series1Name);
    for (Itemdatapoint t : series1List) {
        series1.set(t.getPointdate(), t.getActualnum());
    }

    ChartSeries series2 = new ChartSeries();

    series2Name = "Series 2";
    series2List = facade.chartQuery(idmid, series2Name);
    for (Itemdatapoint t : series2List) {
        series2.set(t.getPointdate(), t.getActualnum());
    }

    lineModel = new LineChartModel();
    lineModel.addSeries(series1);

    if (series2List != null) {
        lineModel.addSeries(series2);
    }
    lineModel.setSeriesColors("FF0000");
    lineModel.setAnimate(true);

    return lineModel;
}
```

Exactly the same method as above is used to successfully produce a bar chart (by using BarChartModel instead of LineChartModel).

**2) The JSF and EL syntax**

I'm using JSF template and the JSF page which calls the bean is:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{dataBean.recid}"/>
    <p:chart type="line" model="#{chartBeanMaster.lineModel}"/>
</h:form>
```

**3) The underlying javascript / jquery**

In the browser console I have a syntax error 'Unexpected Identifier'. The line it refers to is:

```
<div id="j_idt30:j_idt31"></div>
<script id="j_idt30:j_idt31_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','widget_j_idt30_j_idt31',{id:'j_idt30:j_idt31',type:'line',data:[[[Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2015,270],[Mon Jun 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,290],[Sat Aug 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,320],[Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,310]],[[Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2015,210],[Mon Jun 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,215],[Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,250],[Sat Aug 01 00:00:00 PDT 2015,250]],[],[]],seriesColors:['#FF0001'],axes:{xaxis: {label:'',renderer:$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{angle:"0"}},yaxis: {label:'',renderer:$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{angle:"0"}}},series:[{label:'null',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}},{label:'null',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}},{label:'null',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}},{label:'null',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}}],animate:true,datatip:true},'charts');});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-4855814929379738627:5735212027105379706" autocomplete="off" />
```

I can clearly see the data is being imported into the line chart model but can't see from this error message exactly where the syntax is wrong.

The error disappears if the p:chart is wrapped with a p:tabbedView tag in the jsf page but still no chart appears!

Responding to Dijana's comment and my research on similar issues, I tried to include the relevant JS scripts in the page.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces" name="charts/charts.css"/>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="charts/charts.js"/>
```

This results in the same error but IN ADDITION it also gives a 'jQuery not defined' error. So I imported all files I though necessary:

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputScript name="primefaces.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputScript name="charts/charts.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputStylesheet name="charts/charts.css" library="primefaces"/>
```

This took me back to the same error:

**Uncaught Sytax Error: Unexpected Identifier**

At first I thought this was PF failing to import the JS scripts, but if I include or delete the manual imports above I still get the same error. This leads me to think the problem could be a bug in the generated script or in the PF library.

To eliminate the possibility of a buggy PF library i upgraded the library to PF 5.2. I also deleted my server cache, web cache and restarted. NOTHING!

I suspect the problem is with the underlying JS but not sure where to go from here. Does PF have a bug when it comes to dynamically creating line charts? Can anyone suggest an example of how to achieve this successfully? Any guidance on what is causing the syntax error? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
In reponse to BalusC's comment the following is the generated content of HTML `<head>` tag which seems to include only one JS library:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/./css/default.css.xhtml" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/./css/cssLayout.css.xhtml" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml? ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GModule/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.projectStage='Development';}</script>
```

Comment: <h:outputScript name="charts/charts.js" library="primefaces" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="charts/charts.css" library="primefaces" />

Comment: Thanks or the helpful comment Dijana. I spent hours trying to manually import the JS scripts and CSS. See update to the question. This made no difference which suggests that the problem is with the generated JS itself even though the scripts are being correctly imported

Comment: Are you including another copy of jQuery? Can you really assure that the <head> of the generated HTML output contains only one jquery.js file and that it's the one from PrimeFaces?

Comment: I included the generated HTML in an update to the question which seems to contain only one jquery.js file and it is the one from PF. Please let me know if this correct. I should also say that I'm using Jsf templates so I imported the Js from the  templates page as the client page does not have a header tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and solution seems to be simpler than I thought. It had nothing directly to do with JS imports or any PF bug. The problem was my Java code. The original code creates a very long date string which seems to have disrupted the generated JS script for the PF line model. This could be because the string contains a combination of white spaces, colons, etc.

Outputing the toString representation of this date value in the for loop seems to solve the immediate problem:

```
public LineChartModel lineModelMethod() {
ChartSeries series1 = new ChartSeries();
series1Name = "Series 1";
series1List = facade.chartQuery(idmid, series1Name);
for (Itemdatapoint t : series1List) {
    series1.set(t.getPointdate().toString, t.getActualnum());
}

lineModel = new LineChartModel();
lineModel.addSeries(series1);

return lineModel;
}
```

All JS errors disappear and the line chart is correctly rendered.

There could be a problem with this because the date is now a string. This means any date related query parameters (ie: order by) will have to be solved by the JPA before the values are sent to make the chart so the date order is not lost in the chart.